# App crash when tap a cell to download a file and scroll up or down the table

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, tableview

I have an app working fine when I tap a cell to download an audio file, but if I tap a cell then try to scroll up or down before finish downloading it will be crashed!

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    
    let percentege = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedCellIndex) as! AudioTableViewCell
        
        cell.progressV.progress = percentege
        
    }
    
}
```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form your attached image it seems , selectedCellIndex is an optional variable.
So, before using this you need to check if it is nil or not, then you should remove force unwraping to avoid crash like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if self.selectedCellIndex != nil{
        if let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedCellIndex) as? AudioTableViewCell{
            cell.progressV.progress = percentege
        }

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should avoid force unwrap, try using guard statement.

Talking about the crash, have a look if you are updating the selectedCellIndex and calling the same downloading task anywhere. I suspect the selectedCellIndex is setting to some value which is not expected.